Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS on Raspberry Pi - How to downgrade the Kernel
I am currently having trouble finding a tutorial on how to downgrade the kernel of Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS on the Raspberry Pi.
The currently installed kernel version is 5.15.0-1050-raspi.
The Pi version of Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS does not have GRUB installed and is not an option for me either.
The reason why I want to downgrade the kernel: I currently have the problem that my Docker backup based on CIFS shares fails due to I/O errors on reading the share folder.
In the current kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 there is an already confirmed bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2060780
My notebooks installed with Linux Mint are also affected by this bug.
I would like to find out if this also affects the current kernel in the Raspi version.
The Raspberry runs in headless mode and in an DMZ, so the only way to administrate the system is SSH.

Instead of downgrading, I would suggest you instead configure your Pi to boot the earlier kernel (5.15.0-1049-raspi), which is still on the system. In this way, you don't mess up any future kernel upgrades (when the smb issue is fixed).
On the Pi, the kernel files are located in /boot, but the files actually used for booting are inside /boot/firmware.
To boot another kernel, simply replace the files /boot/firmware/initrd.img and /boot/firmware/vmlinuz with the preferred version from /boot:
sudo cp /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-1049-raspi /boot/firmware/vmlinuz
sudo cp /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-1049-raspi /boot/firmware/initrd.img
sudo chmod +rx /boot/firmware/vmlinuz /boot/firmware/initrd.img

And then reboot.
To revert back to the current kernel run:
sudo cp /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-1050-raspi /boot/firmware/vmlinuz
sudo cp /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-1050-raspi /boot/firmware/initrd.img
sudo chmod +rx /boot/firmware/vmlinuz /boot/firmware/initrd.img

When a new kernel becomes available with apt, the files will be overwritten as part of the kernel package's post-install script.
Based on the information from this answer.

Thank you very much Artur, works like a charm! That's what I was looking for.
